# Serialize relations in remote model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, serialization

In my rails app I have 2 "Remote models". Those models are not active_record models and are retrieved on an API using a gem provided by the API.

I send data in hash to the library, and the library give me the data in the form of hashes. My question is more on how to generate correct hashes

My question can be illustrated with the 2 following models ;

remote_user.rb

```
class RemoteUser
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Serialization

attr_accessor(
  :Name
  :Email
  ...)
end

def attributes{ 'Name'=> nil,'Email'=>nil .....}

attr_reader(:HeadquartersAdress)

def HeadquartersAddress=(data={})
if data.is_a? RemoteAdresse
  @HeadquartersAddress=data
else
  @HeadquartersAddress=RemoteAdresse.new(data)
end
end
```

remote_adresse.rb

```
class RemoteAdresse
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Serialization
  attr_accessor(
    :AddressLine1,
    :AddressLine2,
    :City,
    :Region,
    :PostalCode,
    :Country
  )

  def attributes
    {
      'AddressLine1'=>nil,
      'AddressLine2'=>nil,
      'City'=>nil,
      'Region'=>nil,
      'PostalCode'=>nil,
      'Country'=>nil
    }
  end
end
```

Test :

```
test = RemoteUser.new Name: 'Foo'
test.HeadquartersAddress=RemoteAddress.new City: 'singapour'
test.serializable_hash
>{"Name"=>"Foo","HeadquartersAddress"=>#<RemoteAdresse:0xa9c2ef8
  @City="singapour"}
```

I would prefer to have : {"Name"=>"Foo","HeadquartersAddress"=>{
      "City"="singapour"}}

The nested object (adresse) is not serialized. What can I do to make it serialize too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not entirely mistaken, you need to include associations to the `serializable_hash` call like so:

```
test = RemoteUser.new Name: 'Foo'
test.HeadquartersAddress=RemoteAddress.new City: 'singapour'
test.serializable_hash(include: :HeadquarterAddress)
```

If that doesn't work, there's always the possibility to overwrite `read_attribute_for_serialization` and adapted it for the `HeadquarterAddress` attribute.

Comment: Thanks ! it's exactly what I needed.